# Why does 'read' strip out whitespace even with the -N flag?

Tags: bash

According to the manual for `read` (and since it is a builtin, not `man read`, but `help read`):

> `-N nchars` Return only after reading exactly NCHARS characters, unless EOF is encountered or read times out, ignoring any delimiter

However, even if the `-N` flag is used, `read` still seems to want to strip out the delimeter from input data. Take the following data as an example:

```
# readfail.sh - Reads 5 characters at a time, and adds "RegEx style" start and end characters for clarity
while read -r -N 5 data; do
    echo "^${data}\$"
done;

echo "^${data}\$"  # There will be data left over just because of the way `read` uses exit codes
```

And here is the output:

```
$ echo -n "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" | ./readfail.sh
^Lorem$
^ipsu$
^m dol$
^or si$
^t ame$
^t$
```

Notice the second line is only 4 characters long. That is because there is supposed to be a space between `Lorem` and `ipsum`, resulting in the following five-character output: `^ ipsu$`

[I can fix this problem by setting `IFS=` before the loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5024215/617937), however, isn't `read` supposed to be **ignoring** any delimiters because of the `-N` flag? Is this a bug, or intended behavior?

Answer (score 2):

`-N` causes the end-of-line delimiter to be ignored. Bash reads exactly the specified number of characters no matter what these characters are. This is independent from the way what had been read is reported to the script in the form of variable content. That uses the usual `IFS` splitting mechanism.

Comment: I don't follow, where is the _"... is reported to the script in the form of variable content"_ step being taken?

Comment: I could imagine this problem happening if you do something like `data=$(read -N 5)` (I'm not sure if that code actually works, I just mean the assigned value isn't being escaped, and would be equivalent to `data=[space]ipsu`). However, in this case we are "magically" filling the `$data` variable by passing the `data` string to the `read` command.

Comment: @IQAndreas `read data` reports the data that it read by setting `data` to what it read, after `IFS`-based splitting. `read -N 5` reads 5 bytes, and splits them according to the usual rules. That's its job. The option `-N` controls how many bytes are read, not how many bytes are put in variables.